# Redirect to URL with value in a search form using ACTION and POST method

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a search form, where user enter a keyword:

```
<form method="post" action="domain.com/gallery/<?php echo $_POST["something"]; ?>" >
<input type="text" name="something" required/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST["something"])) {
echo $_POST["something"];
}
?>
```

I want go to url "domain.com/gallery/keyword" after form submission.

The problem is that I can't, with the code above it redirects to "domain.com/gallery/", without keyword value...

I'm using POST and ACTION, because "isset($_POST["something"])" is not working with other methods like onsubmit, e.g. "onsubmit="window.location = 'domain.com/gallery/' + something.value; return false;""

Comment: Submit your form to the same page, and get using $_POST the data and then do a [redirect](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php).

Comment: Thanks man, the solution works like a charm! Have a good day.

Comment: Happy to see you've figured it out with my comment! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change the value of action attribute. You can doing it with javascript:

```
<form method="post" action="domain.com/gallery/" onSubmit="changeTarget(this)">
```

The javascript:

```
function changeTarget(currentForm)
{
   //read initial attribute value
   actionAttribute = currentForm.getAttribute('action');
   //read form field value
   enteredKeyword =  currentForm.omething.value;
   //Concantinate both values and set it as new target
   currentForm.setAtrribute('action') = actionAttribute + enteredKeyword;
   
   //Nessacary return statement
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form method="post" action="{samePage}.php" >
<input type="text" name="something" required/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST["something"])) {
$url="domain.com/gallery/".<?php echo $_POST["something"]; 
header("Location: $url")?>
}
?>
```